# Including a text file in LaTeX

Tags: verbatim, input, sourcecode

I write a program by DevC++ compiler and save it by .cpp format, and want to paste the code in my editor, Do I have to paste all the code each time?
Is there a way to include the file instead of copying and pasting the code over and over?
I suppose there should be a way because for a program of about 100 lines the including the file is more convenient.

Comment: You are probably looking for `lstinputlisting`. Just do a quick search here on the site: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=lstinputlisting

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Normally this is done using the `listings` package. It provides a `lstlisting` environment for verbatim code and also a `\lstinputlisting[<options,...>]{<file name>}` to include an external file verbatim. As options you can select `language=C++` to get specific syntax highlighting. I also usually use `basicstyle=\ttfamily`. See the `listings` package manual for more details.

Comment: I actually use this package , all I didn't know was how include my c++ file instead of pasting the code each time .